# Filter all (multiple) workbooks in a folder with a sheet from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, file, filter

I have a (Filtering) workbook with S5 Sheet. I have 56 excel files with S1 sheets with 300 to 400 thousand records each in a folder. If C column of S5 sheet of a  filtering workbook matches AG column of the list of excel files (all) in the folder, I would like to copy matching data from the multiple files and the column data A of S5 (filtering criteria file") in the same row of the new summary sheet. The below Macro I got from a friend works to some extent. I have to run it 56 times like file 1, 2, 3 ... 56. But it takes more than hour and skips records. Is there a better way available? I would appreciate for your help.

```
Sub FilterData ()

    Set kFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set kF = kFS.GetFile("C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\TEST\SrcFile.xlsx")
    Dim mainWB As Workbook
    Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\SrcFile.xlsx")
    mainWB.Sheets("S5").Select
    Dim newLastRow As Long

    'File1
    Set desFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set desF = kFS.GetFile("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\Report\File1.xlsx")
    Dim desWB As Workbook
    Set desWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\Report\File1.xlsx")
    desWB.Sheets("S1").Select

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngName As Range, rngName1 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("C" & i)
        Set rngName1 = mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("A" & i)
        For j = 1 To desWB.Sheets("S1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = desWB.Sheets("S1").Range("AG" & j)
            Set rngName = desWB.Sheets("S1").Rows(j)
            If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                rngName.Copy Destination:=mainWB.Sheets("New").Range("A" & i)
                rngName1.Copy Destination:=mainWB.Sheets("New").Range("AH" & i)

            End If

            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i
    desWB.Close

    newLastRow = mainWB.Sheets("New").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: “Is there a better way available?“ yes, use specific tools for databases. May be Access or others (just google it)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and assuming you dont have any duplicates in sheets "S5" column "C" and that it exists only once in your 56 files.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim mainWB As Workbook, Wb As Workbook
    Dim P1 As Range, c As Range, P2 As Range

    Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\SrcFile.xlsx") 'This is your file with sheet "S5" and "New"
    Folder = "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\Report\" 'This is the folder with all 56 workbooks with sheet "S1"
    File = Dir(Folder & "*.xlsx")

    Set P1 = mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("C1:C" & mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each c In P1: D1(c.Value) = c.Row: Next c

    Do While File <> ""
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Folder & File)
        Set P2 = Wb.Sheets("S1").Range("A1", Wb.Sheets("S1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        T1 = P2

        For i = 1 To UBound(T1)
            If D1.exists(T1(i, 33)) Then
                For j = 1 To 33
                    mainWB.Sheets("New").Cells(D1(T1(i, 33)), j) = T1(i, j)
                Next j
                mainWB.Sheets("New").Cells(D1(T1(i, 33)), 34) = mainWB.Sheets("S5").Cells(D1(T1(i, 33)), 1)
            End If
        Next i

        Wb.Saved = True
        Wb.Close
        File = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim mainWB As Workbook, Wb As Workbook
    Dim P1 As Range, c As Range, P2 As Range, a As Integer
    Dim T2()

    Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\SrcFile.xlsx") 'This is your file with sheet "S5" and "New"
    Folder = "C:\Users\tech\Desktop\TEST\Report\" 'This is the folder with all 56 workbooks with sheet "S1"
    File = Dir(Folder & "*.xlsx")

    mainWB.Sheets("New").Cells.Clear

    Set P1 = mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("C1:C" & mainWB.Sheets("S5").Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row)
    a = 1

    For Each c In P1: D1(c.Value) = c.Offset(0, -2).Value: Next c

    Do While File <> ""
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Folder & File)
        Set P2 = Wb.Sheets("S1").Range("A1", Wb.Sheets("S1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        T1 = P2

        For i = 1 To UBound(T1)
            If D1.exists(T1(i, 33)) Then
                ReDim Preserve T2(1 To 34, 1 To a)
                For j = 1 To 33
                    T2(j, a) = T1(i, j)
                Next j
                T2(34, a) = D1(T1(i, 33))
                a = a + 1
            End If
        Next i

        Wb.Saved = True
        Wb.Close
        File = Dir()
    Loop

    mainWB.Sheets("New").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(T2, 2), UBound(T2)) = Application.Transpose(T2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This macro is swift. but did not pull any records. May be the information I provided is not adequate.  Sheet S5 has no duplicate variable in C column. But other S1 Sheets in the multiple workbook may have duplicate values and they need to be pulled in Sheet "New".

Comment: When you say "in the same row of the new summary sheet" did you mean same row as in "data from S1 and from S5 on one line" or as in same row as matching data in S5 ? I took the second option, that's why you might have results all over the New sheet if any. I'am gonna edit this.

Comment: you have understood right. I mean second option. after matching column C of S5 and AG of S1,  corresponding column A  of S5 data should be copied along with the data from S1 worksheets from multiple workbooks.

Comment: Thank you so much AmBo. It was the great solution. 56 files with 200K to 300K files. it pulled data in less than 3 minutes. Wonderful.

Comment: It works swiftly with all the files EXCEPT one huge file with over 500K records for the current year. Surprising, as the data type is the same like other 55 files. I checked for data error, not found.  It gives error at the last line of Code with "Type mismatch (Error 13)" at mainWB.sheets.... Is there any solution for that? Thanks for your help.